# Finding the square root of a given number using bitwise operations

Tags: algorithm

Is there an algorithm to find the square root of a given number using bitwise operations?

Comment: Probably you mean this: "Is there an algorithm to find the square root of a given number using bitwise operations"?

Comment: try to look at this page - http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/sqroot.html#implementations

Comment: yes   i need algorithm for find square root using bitwise operations

Comment: Are you interested in an integer square root? or one that includes floating point?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is [this famous piece of code magic](http://www.lomont.org/Math/Papers/2003/InvSqrt.pdf) that computes *inverse* square root with a some very clever bit twiddling. It is wrongfully attributed to John Carmack - [here's a deeper dig](http://www.beyond3d.com/content/articles/8/) into its origin. Maybe that's what you're asking about?

I wouldn't suggest using it, though. On modern CPU's it cannot beat dedicated transcendental instructions. Your usual c++ intrinsic `sqrt()` would probably beat it hands down.

[Edit:] The cited article describes a general derivation method for such fast approximations, and explicitly states 'Derive a similar method for sqrt(x)' as a homework problem at its final lines. So you should be able to track its reasoning and devise a similar method for sqrt (without the reciprocal) directly.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) has an article about and a code too. And [another wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_nth-root_algorithm) shows an algorithm (even for roots greater than 2) that can be easily implemented in binary (so, involving operation on bits).

If you want to stick only to real bitwise operators, you have to implement `+` using Ands, Ors, Xors, Nots... If you want to do it on floats according to IEEE, you need more work (the first code in wikipedia could be used on the mantissa "directly", likely under certain restriction, and adjust exponent "accordingly"... you have to figure out how, however!)

Answer (score 1):

No... I'm assuming it's for the sake of performance? If so, the best you are probably going to get is using a lookup table. If you have the option to work with integer math (ex. by working with numbers multiplied by 10, 100 or 1000 instead of floats) you can use bitwise rotation to quickly throw off unneeded precision and jump into a lookup table.